# Update a record of DB if it exists after importing a Csv file in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using `Maatwebsite\Excel` to import a csv file to store new users in the DB. If i have already a record in DB with the same data it creates and error. How can i update the record if it exists ?

My import class is :

```js
class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
            'password' => $row['pass'],
            'created_at' => $row['registered'],
        ]);
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ","
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the `WithUpserts` interface. Also you need to specify which field should be unique so if it exists, it will update the record, else it will create new one.

Assuming your unique column is email, change your code to the following:

```php
class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithHeadingRow, WithUpserts
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'firstname' => $row['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $row['lastname'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
            'password' => $row['pass'],
            'created_at' => $row['registered'],
        ]);
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ","
        ];
    }

    public function uniqueBy()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
}
```